# How to store data (locally) against a Google Sign In user?

Tags: javascript, php, database, oauth, google-signin

I'm looking to use Google Sign In for a website I'm working on and I've successfully got a Google Sign In button working and returning profile information for the chosen user.

My question is now when using this on a website which needs to keep some kind of persistence through pages (using a RESTful design) how do I link my local database (with information related to the users account on my website) with their Google User.

The information I'm getting back from the profile information is:

- ID
- Name
- Image
- Email

It says in an explicit comment next to the ID in the example code: `// Don't send this directly to your server!`. So I assume I shouldn't store an entry in my users database table using the ID, so what am I supposed to use? I kind find much information relating to this online, am I approaching this entirely incorrectly?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe they mean you should be running your own user database that mirror the user infos, but has its own ID system?

Comment: That's what I assume, but I'm asking what information from Google do I use to associate that user with the information in my database? It says not to send the ID to my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've solved it. I didn't read fully the API documentation and I was missing out the whole authentication step.

I / you need to use the returned authenticated `sub` value from Google's authentication server to store data against.

**Ref:** https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth